# Asp.Net Control inside Jquery AJAX

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, postback

On my page (root folder) I am opening a dialog with ajax loaded content (jQuery) taken from `~/ajax/WebPage.aspx?id=1`. The content has an asp.net server control (a button). The problem is when I click on the button a postback happens, but instead of posting to `~/ajax/WebPage.aspx?id=1` it goes to `~/WebPage.aspx?id=1` which of course does not exist.

What is a fix, I don't want to move my ajax page to the root folder, because it may be called from multiple places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [Button.PostBackUrl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl.aspx) to `~/ajax/WebPage.aspx?id=1`

**Edit**
Since you are using jQuery to load and not the UpdatePanel, use a HTML button and wire up the click event to a Javascript function that can use jQuery to do the server communication.

Comment: okay, it is something, it works, but the problem is when I click on the button it does a full postback to the `PostBackUrl` address, even the button is inside an `UpdatePanel`. What I want is to submit a form without redirecting to another page (button inside the dialog should not reload or navigate away from the current page).